# What is a good XML visualization tool?

Tags: xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML Visualization tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938535/xml-visualization-tool)

What is a good XML visualization tool? In a more document friendly way. XML spy had a grid view but that wasn't decent enough to paste in a design document